# How to connect a web app in a pc with a database on another pc using php mysql XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, server, xampp

I have a web app in php mysql programmed with xampp server.

I need to have the web server with the app files in one pc on xammp and connect it to a mysql database on another pc using xampp also I imagine on phpmyadmin as usual.

I don't know how to redirect the database, as in one pc you just put the dB name in the queries but I don't know how to do it if the database is on another pc.

I couldn't find any info online, I already can access my xampp server through ip address on another devices but with the web server and the dB server on the same pc.

I need to have the web app files in one pc and the database in another, using xampp in both pc. So I can connect other devices as clients and use the web app normally.

Please help:( it is for a project :(

Edit:
I am beginner, so I really would like a detailed explanation with examples please so I can replicate it.

Comment: 1. Make sure the database is accessible for other computers (and that no firewall is blocking the port MySQL are using, normally 3306 for incoming request). 2. Make sure you have set up and are using a MySQL user that are allowed to connect from the other IP. 3. When you connect to MySQL in your code, just put the other computers IP and use the MySQL user mentioned in point 2.

Comment: connect to mysql with ip and  mysql port of the system where you are running database. That's all.

Comment: Fo you have a practical example of how can I achieve that?